# How to create separate lists for each set of matching characters are found in a multi-line string

Tags: python-2.7

What is the best way to create separate lists for each set of matching characters found in a multi-line string ?

```
str="""Name: abc1
Age: defg1
Place: xyz1

Name: abc2
Age: defg2
Place: xyz2

Name: abc3
Age: defg3
Place: xyz3
"""
```

Using the below code I am able to create one big list but interested in creating three separate lists.

```
my_list = []
for each_module in str.split("\n"):
        if "Name: " in each_module:
                my_list.append(each_module.strip("Name: "))
        elif "Age: " in each_module:
                my_list.append(each_module.strip("Age: "))
        elif "Place: " in each_module:
                my_list.append(each_module.strip("Place: "))
print my_list
```

Output:

```
['abc1', 'defg1', 'xyz1', 'abc2', 'defg2', 'xyz2', 'abc3', 'defg3', 'xyz3']
```

Preferred Output:

```
['abc1', 'defg1', 'xyz1']
['abc2', 'defg2', 'xyz2']
['abc3', 'defg3', 'xyz3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are well started, just create a new list that you reset when you fill out the place, and add it to your main list as below:

```
my_str="""Name: abc1
Age: defg1
Place: xyz1

Name: abc2
Age: defg2
Place: xyz2

Name: abc3
Age: defg3
Place: xyz3
"""
my_list = []
new_list = []
for each_module in my_str.split("\n"):
    if "Name: " in each_module:
        new_list.append(each_module.strip("Name: "))
    elif "Age: " in each_module:
        new_list.append(each_module.strip("Age: "))
    elif "Place: " in each_module:
        new_list.append(each_module.strip("Place: "))
        my_list.append(new_list)
        new_list = []
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[['bc1', 'defg1', 'xyz1'], ['bc2', 'defg2', 'xyz2'], ['bc3', 'defg3', 'xyz3']]
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but I am actually looking for the values of each item in a list.
For example: 
[John, 22, USA]
[David, 23, UK]

Comment: I updated my answer because I realized that you were using a predefined variable named `str` that I fixed after.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking. Works perfectly.